# Tkinter Frame always has height 1 when using grid_propagate(False)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
#gui.py
from .stock import getFruitStockInParalel, getTimeTillRestock
from tkscrolledframe import ScrolledFrame
import tkinter as tk


class StockFrame(ScrolledFrame):
    BG = "#90A4AE"

    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        #Create variables
        self.lVisible = False
        self.blVisible = False

        self.cFruitLabels = list()
        self.lFruitLabels = list()
        self.blFruitLabels = list()

        self.cFruits = list()
        self.lFruits = list()
        self.blFruits = list()
        self.cFruits, self.lFruits, self.blFruits = getFruitStockInParalel()

        #Create Frame inside parent ScrolledFrame
        self.mainFrame = self.display_widget(tk.Frame, fit_width=True)
        self.mainFrame.config(borderwidth=3, background=self.BG)
        self.mainFrame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.mainFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="stockframe")
        self.mainFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="stockframe")

        #Create and place Label that displays time till restock
        self.timeTillRestockLabel = tk.Label(self.mainFrame, text="", anchor=tk.W, font=("Segoe UI", 10), bg="white", relief="ridge", borderwidth=2, padx=5, pady=2)
        self.timeTillRestockLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, padx=6, columnspan=2, pady=5)

        #Create and place Buttons that toggle last and before last stock
        self.lButton = tk.Button(self.mainFrame, text="Toggle Last Stock", command=self.toggleLastStock, padx=100, bg="white")
        self.lButton.grid(row=100, columnspan=2, column=0, padx=7, pady=0, sticky=tk.W)

        self.blButton = tk.Button(self.mainFrame, text="Toggle Before Last Stock", command=self.toggleBlastStock, padx=100, bg="white")
        self.blButton.grid(row=102, columnspan=2, column=0, padx=7, pady=(5,0), sticky=tk.W)

        #Create lFrame and blFrame
        self.lFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame, bg=self.BG)
        self.lFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="lframe")
        self.lFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="lframe")

        self.blFrame = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame, bg=self.BG)
        self.blFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="blframe")
        self.blFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="blframe")

        #Start loops
        self.mainLoop()
        self.timeRemainingLoop()


#Loops
    def mainLoop(self):
        self.updateCurrentFruits()
        self.updatelFrame()
        self.updateblFrame()

        self.bindAllToScrollWheel(self)

        self.after(60*5*1000, self.mainLoop)


    def timeRemainingLoop(self):
        self.timeTillRestockLabel.config(text="Time till restock: "+str(getTimeTillRestock()).split(".")[0])

        self.after(1, self.timeRemainingLoop)


    def bindAllToScrollWheel(self, parent):
        #Recursively bind all widgets in parent to scroll wheel
        for widget in parent.winfo_children():
            self.bindAllToScrollWheel(widget)
        self.bind_scroll_wheel(parent)

#Fruit labels
    def updateCurrentFruits(self):
        #Destroy previous fruit labels
        for fl in self.cFruitLabels: 
            fl.destroy()

        self.cFruitLabels.clear()

        #Create new fruit labels and place them
        for fruit in self.cFruits:
            self.cFruitLabels.append(fruitLabel(self.mainFrame, fruit.name, usePrice=True))

        for i, fl in enumerate(self.cFruitLabels):
            fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), pady=(0,5))
    
    def updatelFrame(self):
        #Destroy previous fruit labels in lFrame
        for fl in self.lFruitLabels: 
                fl.destroy()

        self.lFruitLabels.clear()

        #Create new fruit labels and place them
        for fruit in self.lFruits:
            self.lFruitLabels.append(fruitLabel(self.lFrame, fruit.name, usePrice=True))

        for i, fl in enumerate(self.lFruitLabels):
            fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), padx=7, pady=(5,1))

    def updateblFrame(self):
        #Destroy previous fruit labels in blFrame
        for fl in self.blFruitLabels: 
            fl.destroy()

        self.blFruitLabels.clear()

        #Create new fruit labels and place them
        for fruit in self.blFruits:
            self.blFruitLabels.append(fruitLabel(self.blFrame, fruit.name, usePrice=True))

        for i, fl in enumerate(self.blFruitLabels):
            fl.grid(row=(i//2)+1, column=int((not i%2 == 0)), padx=7, pady=(5,1))


#Toggle last and before last stocks
    def toggleLastStock(self):
        if not self.lVisible:
            self.lVisible = True
            self.lFrame.grid(row=101, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        elif self.lVisible:
            self.lVisible = False
            self.lFrame.grid_forget()
        
    def toggleBlastStock(self):
        if not self.blVisible:
            self.blVisible = True
            self.blFrame.grid(row=103, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

        elif self.blVisible:
            self.blVisible = False
            self.blFrame.grid_forget()
```

This is the class I created in gui.py

`fruitLabel` is a function that returns a Frame with a few things based on the fruitName. I have checked and it works perfectly but if it is relevant comment and I'll add the code for it

```
#main.py
import tkinter as tk
from scripts.gui import *
from scripts.value import saveFruitValues

#Segoe UI
#90A4AE

#Create main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x800")
root.iconbitmap("assets/kitsune.ico")
root.title("Blox Fruits")
root.resizable(0,0)

#Update fruit values when starting
saveFruitValues()

stockFrame = StockFrame(root, relief="solid", scrollbars="vertical", width=200)
stockFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.W + tk.S)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.update_idletasks()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the code I'm running in main.py

Now if in the StockFrame class I specify the height of self.mainFrame, so like this
`self.mainFrame.config(borderwidth=3, background=self.BG, height=1500)` it all works perfectly.
However, since the size required for self.mainFrame isn't always the same, I'd have to set this height to a value that would most of the time be too big, which then results in there being a lot of empty space you can still scroll through.

But, if I don't set the height, then it just uses 1 as the height and all that shows in a single row of pixels inside the ScrolledFrame

What could be going on?

(Btw I'm only now learning how to do gui stuff with classes so if anything I did is out of convention or not good I'd apreciate the info thanks)

Edit:

[image]

Edit 2:
I've tried creating a function that gets the right height for the Frame before setting grid_propagate back to false, like this:

```
def updateHeight(self):
        #Updates mainFrame height
        self.mainFrame.grid_propagate(True)

        self.mainFrame.update_idletasks()

        reqHeight = self.mainFrame.winfo_reqheight()
        if reqHeight < self.winfo_height(): reqHeight = self.winfo_height()

        self.mainFrame.grid_propagate(False)

        self.mainFrame.config(height=reqHeight)
```

And then I call it in mainLoop like this:

```
def mainLoop(self):
        self.updateCurrentFruits()
        self.updatelFrame()
        self.updateblFrame()

        self.updateHeight()

        self.bindAllToScrollWheel(self)

        self.after(60*5*1000, self.mainLoop)
```

This almost works, but I'm running into a new weird issue
Now, when I first run the program, I'm able to scroll up for some reason. However, if I click on either of the buttons it starts working fine
(if what I said doesn't make sense check this streamable link https://streamable.com/c1tw2k)

Comment: Try removing `self.mainFrame.grid_propagate(False)`.

Comment: That fixed the height issue but now my widgets are cropped by the ScrolledFrame. See the screenshot I added to the question

Comment: It is because you set the width of `StockFrame` to 200.

Comment: But why is the Frame inside larger then

Comment: Why do you think that the inner frame cannot be larger?

Comment: I dont know...? I did use fit_width=True which according to the documentation should stretch the widget returned to fit the ScrolledFrame's width

Comment: It is the widgets inside the frame that are larger than the width of the frame.

Comment: Ok do you know how to fix it

Comment: Remove `padx=100` when creating those buttons, and change `sticky=tk.W` to `sticky=tk.EW` when gridding them.

Comment: But the fruit labels are also getting cropped
Not even cropped, they're just entirely outside the frame. In the screenshot I added to the post there were two fruit labels but the one on the right didn't appear entirely

Comment: Yes, the fruit label on the right (put in column 1) is pushed out of the viewable area because of the long buttons.  It should be shown if the suggestions in my last comment is used.

Comment: Ay it fixed it thanks. I actually did get the updateHeight function to work after a while but this is much better tysm I just set that padding without thinking haha

Comment: Actually I just realised that the issue with scrolling up with the empty space is still there, and now it doesn't even go away when one of the buttons are clicked